# Select a Column from a given range by Address

Tags: vba, excel

When I am selecting ranges from a `WorkSheet` object one method I can use is `MySheet.Range("A1")`. Is there a similar approach I can use to select a *subrange* of an existing range object?

To make my question more concrete here is an example:

Let's say that when the selection changes on a particular worksheet I want to tell the user how many "Column I" cells are in this range. With my current understanding of VBA I would do something like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim col As Range
    For Each col In Target.Columns
        If col.Column = Range("I:I").Column Then
            MsgBox col.Rows.Count
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there a more flexible way to index a subrange?

Comment: Are you saying if a user selects `H1:J3` you want to select the sub-range `I1:I3`?

Comment: As an example yes! I think that Alex K.'s answer is what I am looking for. But if you have another suggestion I would be happy to expand my options :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way looking at the intersection:

```
Dim ir As Range
Set ir = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("I:I"))
If Not ir Is Nothing Then MsgBox ir.Cells.Count
```

Comment: Good idea! Thanks for the help :)